# 404 returned when trying to access url (Kubernetes/Helm/Ingress)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

## The problem

I'm currently working on a webAPI which I have an nginx ingress controller controlling traffic to my cluster.

I have got it 90% working where the paths for pgweb (http://lnd.local/pgweb) and grafana (http:lnd.local/grafana) are working.

But I have an express server that handles requests to (http://lnd.local/wallets/?) and I am currently getting 404 responses from this address.

I expect to be able to perform REST requests to this endpoint.

Currently I don't have any specific error messages besides the 404. I have checked that that services for the express server exist and so does the ingress (will attach screenshots).

## What I've tried

I have been double checking my other ingress and seeing if I'm missing something and was looking in the ingress logs but am yet to find anything.

## My Code

### Express Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-service
  labels: 
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-service
spec: 
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.walletApi.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.walletApi.port }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-deployment
```

### Deployoment File for Express service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-node-deployment
      annotations:
          prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
          prometheus.io/path: /metrics
          prometheus.io/port: "{{ .Values.walletApi.port }}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node
          image: node-wallet:{{ $.Chart.Version }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.walletApi.port }}
          env:
            - name: CLUSTER_DB_HOST
              value: "{{ .Values.clusterDb.host }}"
            - name: CLUSTER_DB_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.clusterDb.port }}"
            - name: CLUSTER_DB_NAME
              value: wallet
```

### Ingress.yaml for pgweb and express server

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wallet-server
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "lnd.local"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /wallets(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Chart.Name }}-node-service
            port:
              number: {{ $.Values.walletApi.port }}
      - path: /pgweb/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Chart.Name }}-pgweb-svc
            port:
              number: {{ $.Values.pgWebApi.port }}
      - path: /static/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ $.Chart.Name }}-pgweb-svc
            port:
              number: {{ $.Values.pgWebApi.port }}
```

### IngressNginx

```
ingress-nginx:
  controller:
    kind: DaemonSet
    hostPort:
      enabled: true
```

### kubectl describe ingress -A output

[kubectl describe ingress output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyibQ.png)

### Conclusion

I'm hoping I'm just missing something small. But I would appreciate any help. I'm stilling learning about Ingress and would love some advice.
If there are any other clarifications I can add feel free to chuck me a comment.

Comment: Hey @hasosi8498! What endpoint is your Nodejs expecting to serve at? To elaborate, in your Express code, is your router looking for `/wallets` or `/`?

Comment: The endpoint is looking for /wallets.

Comment: Router*  - Thanks for the reply @thanatonian2311